Optimization of Radix Sort Implementation: Slower than Expected Compared to Standard Sort
The same SO question was originally posted here in Python. Following the advice of @user24714692, I coded everything in CPP and created a new question.
I've implemented a version of radix sort (the version that allows sorting integers whose values go up to n² where n is the size of the list to sort) in C++ for benchmarking against the standard built in sort (a 3-part hybrid sorting algorithm).
Surprisingly, my radix sort implementation, even without using a hashmap (using a direct access array instead), is slower than the standard sort even for larger input sizes. Since I'm O(n) and the built-in is O(nlogn) there should be ways to micro optimise my coded. I'm seeking advice on optimizing my implementation to achieve better performance. I'm not doing this for practical purposes but just for learning purposes as I'm fairly new to programming, therefore I'm not looking for external libraries to magically improve my code without understand why it makes it better.
Are there micro-optimisations I could bring? Is my code really O(n)?
Things that were tried: using reserve to avoid the downside of push_back. Worked ok. Using linked lists, worked when implemented as 3 arrays (https://pastebin.com/9Bviux9C) but did not when creating a class Node and an array of Linked Lists (https://pastebin.com/y8V95hd7).
Time is expressed in seconds:
Size                                    Radix Sort                              Radix Sort Reserve                      Radix Sort Linked List                  Radix Sort Linked List Arr              std::sort
1.000e+01                               3.500e-06                               3.100e-06                               1.600e-06                               4.000e-07                               2.000e-07
1.000e+03                               1.303e-04                               1.436e-04                               1.119e-04                               3.420e-05                               2.080e-05
1.000e+04                               1.132e-03                               1.240e-03                               1.043e-03                               3.119e-04                               2.594e-04
1.000e+05                               1.256e-02                               1.546e-02                               1.324e-02                               3.569e-03                               3.112e-03
2.000e+05                               2.681e-02                               3.355e-02                               3.586e-02                               5.727e-03                               6.551e-03
1.000e+06                               3.385e-01                               1.870e-01                               3.620e-01                               3.996e-02                               3.737e-02
2.000e+06                               8.214e-01                               3.920e-01                               8.885e-01                               1.163e-01                               7.740e-02
3.000e+06                               1.341e+00                               6.217e-01                               1.488e+00                               1.664e-01                               1.186e-01
4.000e+06                               1.998e+00                               8.691e-01                               2.180e+00                               2.414e-01                               1.703e-01
5.000e+06                               2.453e+00                               1.103e+00                               2.866e+00                               3.164e-01                               2.230e-01
6.000e+06                               3.156e+00                               1.295e+00                               3.245e+00                               3.668e-01                               2.599e-01
7.000e+06                               3.524e+00                               1.606e+00                               3.903e+00                               4.312e-01                               3.016e-01
8.000e+06                               3.997e+00                               1.620e+00                               4.418e+00                               5.400e-01                               3.577e-01
9.000e+06                               4.687e+00                               1.916e+00                               5.061e+00                               5.873e-01                               3.959e-01
1.000e+07                               5.126e+00                               2.078e+00                               5.744e+00                               6.541e-01                               4.449e-01
1.500e+07                               8.023e+00                               3.115e+00                               8.780e+00                               1.005e+00                               6.654e-01
2.500e+07                               1.398e+01                               5.379e+00                               1.689e+01                               1.726e+00                               1.133e+00
3.500e+07                               2.232e+01                               7.867e+00                               2.573e+01                               2.374e+00                               1.617e+00
4.500e+07                               3.516e+01                               1.176e+01                               3.824e+01                               3.332e+00                               2.126e+00
5.500e+07                               4.483e+01                               1.571e+01                               4.708e+01                               3.857e+00                               2.554e+00

Code used:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>

void radix_sort_no_hashmap(std::vector<long long>& arr, long long size) {
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> least_sig_digit(size);
    for (long long num : arr) {
        long long q = num / size;
        long long r = num % size;
        least_sig_digit[r].push_back(q);
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> highest_sig_digit(size);
    for (long long k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
        for (long long q : least_sig_digit[k]) {
            highest_sig_digit[q].push_back(q * size + k);
        }
    }
    long long i = 0;
    for (long long k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
        for (long long num : highest_sig_digit[k]) {
            arr[i++] = num;
        }
    }
}

void benchmark_sorting_algorithms(std::vector<long long>& sizes, std::vector<double>& radix_times, std::vector<double>& std_sort_times) {
    for (long long size : sizes) {
        std::vector<long long> array(size);

        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> dis(0, size*size-1);

        for (long long& num : array) {
            num = dis(gen);
        }

        auto new_arr1 = array;
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        radix_sort_no_hashmap(new_arr1, size);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        radix_times.push_back(std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count());

        auto new_arr2 = array;
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::sort(new_arr2.begin(), new_arr2.end());
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std_sort_times.push_back(std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count());

        // Make sure that the arrays are sorted correctly
        for (long long i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (new_arr1[i] != new_arr2[i]) {
                std::cout << "Sorting failed\n";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<long long> sizes = {1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 10000000};
    std::vector<double> radix_times;
    std::vector<double> std_sort_times;

    benchmark_sorting_algorithms(sizes, radix_times, std_sort_times);

    std::cout << "Size\t\tRadix Sort No Hashmap\t\tstd::sort\n";
    for (long long i = 0; i < sizes.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(3) << (float)sizes[i] << "\t\t" << radix_times[i] << "\t\t" << std_sort_times[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

EDIT:
I used -O3
EDIT2:
Plot

EDIT3:
Printing Time/n:

The built-in that is supposed to be O(nlogn) looks surprising constant when doing Time/n. I don't know why.

std::vector<std::vector<T>> is probably a bad idea when it comes to performance

Since I needed a dynamic array, I thought about a vector. Should I use an array of linked lists instead?

Did you compile with optimizations on? Using high_resolution_clock is also not recommnended (use a profiler) or at least steady_clock

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows A single dimensional vector is ok, so you get contiguous memory allocation. If you have 2D data do the indexing calculations yourself. (Contiguous memory is preferable wrt caching of data)

" O(n) and the built-in is O(nlogn)" only means that there is some n above which you can expect one to take less time than the other. It does not mean that one is always faster than the other. And the turning point where the O(n) is actually faster can be so large n that practically its slower

radix_sort_no_hashmap is doing a lot of push_backs which might need to realloc which is inefficient.

@PepijnKramer I compiled with no optimisations. I added the results with -O3 in the post.

calling push_back often without reserving upfront is potentially very slow. Either resize or reserve right at the start

when optimizing an algorithm you should always use a profiler. That will tell you where the real bottleneck is. The problem might even be that your radix sort has more missed branche predictions then the std::sort implementation. That could be enough to make it perform worse.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I know but since log2(10^7) is around 23.5 I expected radix sort to be at least catching up

ypu have the numbers, you can plot them. You cannot use it to know if it is O(n) for sure, but you can get a first idea whether it is linear or worse

From a short view I see some problems. You are accessing a single element (2d vector?) and kill any kind of stream line of data. It is much better to have a constant data stream. Manual loop unrolling can also help a lot to help using the pipeline of your cpu.

I added a plot @463035818_is_not_an_ai, it seems linear (at least not quadratic).

@akirahinoshiro I'm not sure I'm familiar with those notions, I'm new to programming, would you mind explaining a bit more in depth?

your axis are logarithmic, only because of that both look linear

Echoing the need for a profiler here.  You might want to specifically look at a cache profiler, since cache efficiency matters a lot more than most people realize.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai my bad, I see sorry

You're doing a lot of memory allocations and deallocations - creating, expanding, and destroying twenty million vectors takes plenty of time. Also, 1000000000n is O(n) while 0.000000001n*lg(n) is O(n * lg(n)) - you can't simply compare big-O complexities.

for the plot you can divide the runtimes by N. If your algorithm is linear you will get a constant. And the difference to the other becomes easier visible. But again, this is only to get some nice visualization. You cannot draw conclusions on the actual asymptotic behavior from the plot alone.

see here for what you can gain by calling reserve https://godbolt.org/z/Tfr1vjrsh. It compares yours and yours+2 lines added. And that is just the very first measure one can take

it uses a s**tload of memory though :D

I get Program terminated with signal: SIGKILL quite quickly (300000)- I don't think it can allocate large amount of memories at once; I'm not sure why though. It happened when I tried using an array of vectors instead of a vector of vectors.

Currently implementing an array of Linked List approach which looks a tiny tiny bit faster than with vectors

my second attempt https://godbolt.org/z/96P13vzEa. Note that in terms of big-O the two variants are the same but the actual runtime differs by orders of magnitude

@463035818_is_not_an_ai how come the nlogn algorithm, when plotting time/n looks that much of a constant? I know log(n) is hard to picture but there should be a difference between log(5*10^7) and log(10^7) (a difference strictly higher than 4 for those numbers which I cannot see at all on the plot)

you are still expecting the runtime to directly follow the big O trend. Thats a misunderstanding. I think it is best illustrated in terms of a counter example: https://godbolt.org/z/nadPb3jb6 here foo has quadratic complexity, but if your input is too low you wont see it.

Could you include std::stable_sort?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Sure, you can make up such artificial examples. But with regular sorting of tens of millions of random numbers, I'd expect "the big O trend" to appear and show some increase. Especially since larger data might also mean more cache misses and also cause some increase. Waving this away like you're trying to is not convincing.

my counter example is of course totally exaggerated to get the point across. More cache misses is not what O(n logn) of std::sort is about. That O(n logn) is neglecting any cache, it is merely about algorithmic complexity, how often the comparison is called and how many swaps are made. Cache misses explain that you see deviation from the big-O trend rather than being more reason to expect a clear nlogn trend

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I didn't say cache misses is what O(n logn) is about or even that it has anything to do with it. I just mentioned it as another reason I'd expect some increase in time (per element). Though it does increase at lower sizes, could be that the size is already well past caches, and that there's an O(n) cost for swaps/memory access that dominates in this size range.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I understand your example but the  sorts I know (heap sort, merge sort, memory sort) all have a logn factor « straight away ». I might be wrong but it’s hard to imagine any sorting algorithm who’d have a logn only pop after a certain n. Which is why I was a bit puzzled, especially since I tested up to 100000000 which is not that small

the example was only the most generic way of demonstrating that something like O(nlogn) + O(n) can be dominated by O(n) even if n is as large as 100000000. Dont get to hang up by the silly example. All I am saying is that it shouldnt come as a surprise to see almost linear trend even though the algorithmic complexity is O(nlogn)

Ah i see so for example if we have O(nlogn)+O(100*n) we won’t see the log since 2^64 is literally the limit in the standard 64-bit model of computation

for example yes. As others suggested you would use a profiler to better understand where the time is spend. I am not too familiar with cost of std::vector allocations, but consider that you you allocate 2  * size small vectors. So as first approximation we can expect that to have a cost linear in size

The main problem in terms of performance is that your code does a lot of memory allocations. It is very costly. Each vector in your 2D vector you grow dynamically. It means that on the first .push_back() call it allocates space for 1 or 2 elements, then on the third call allocates space for 4 elements and copies all the date it had into a newly allocated memory location. Then 8 and so on. The values above are implementation dependent and are not precise. But the idea is correct. Vector expansion is costly.
std::sort, contrary, is implemented completely inplace. It does not allocate any additional space to sort a range.
You can avoid those allocations by calling .reserve(<needed memory capacity>) on vectors you plan to populate. This solution works fine, if you know how many elements will your vector have. Or can come up with some estimation based on some empirical knowledge. So your loops will look like this:
std::vector<std::vector<long long>> least_sig_digit(size);
for(auto& loc_arr : least_sig_digit){
    loc_arr.reserve(<your future size estimation>)
}
for (long long num : arr) {
    long long q = num / size;
    long long r = num % size;
    least_sig_digit[r].push_back(q);
}

This change to the way how you populate your vectors will improve your code performance significanlty.
If you do not have any estimation of your vector future size, you can try to use std::deque instead of std::vector. It has different allocation policy, which in your case may end up in less allocations in total. std::deque allocates memory in a fixed size chunks and does not copy data from old place to a new one. So sometimes, when you have to deal with dynamic growth it can be faster. But you will pay with slower access to elements and slower iteration through the deque.
It was a long time ago, when I wrote my radix sort.
But I would also suggest you to split your elements into "words" for radix sort differently. Now you do a dynamic split. I mean, your "word" size is defined by size, which you pass during runtime. You can fix that size based on the type size. You are using int64_t. Split each value into four 16 byte words. With that you will fix the size of your "inner" vectors by 4 and will be able to use std::vector<std::array<4, uint16_t>> instead std::vector<std::vector<std::uint64_t>>. It will require a bit more work, in terms that you will need to go through the array 4 times, but it will also have better memory locality, so can end up good.
Performance is about experimenting and measuring. Very few things are guaranteed, but many can be worth of trying :)
